# How do negative exponents affect the + and - signs in a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand that when such a fractions has an even exponent the sign becomes the opposite. Like such: $(-\frac{1}{2})^4 = (+\frac{1}{2})$. Right?

---

I don't know what sign this $(-\frac12)^
{-4}$ will have by the end.

Comment: $$\left(-\frac 12\right)^{-4} = \left(\frac 1{-\frac 12}\right)^4= (-2)^4 = +16$$  Note that $\left(-\frac 12\right)^4 = \frac 1{16}$ which is positive.

Answer (score 1):

When you are confused, return to the definitions. The definition of $(-1/4)^4$ is

$$\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{256}.$$

When we have a negative number for the exponent, we have

$$\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-4}=\frac{1}{\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{256}}=256.$$

Comment: The question is about $\left(-\frac 12\right)^4$.  and $\left(-\frac 12\right)^{-4}$